# Well structured data

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, admissibility

In the paper ["Admissible clustering procedures"](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/58/1/91/224825/Admissible-clustering-procedures) the authors Van Ness and Fisher (1971) have explained well structured data as follows:

Data is said to be well structured if it has exact tree structure, i.e. if one can reconstruct the similarity matrix of the data from knowledge of the hierarchical tree alone.

I am not able to imagine an example of this kind of data specially for euclidean distance based similarity where distance or similarity can attain any value. Please help me find such an example if it exists.

Practically I think it is required that $s(x,y)>s(a,b) \implies d(x,y)>d(a,b) $ where $s$ is similarity matrix, $d(x,y)$ is the maximum level at which subtree containing $x$ and $y$ is formed  where $o$ indicates cluster having entire data (so points similar to each other will merge at a higher level, i.e. closer to leaves)

Edit1: Just came across an article saying exact trees are possible only in ultrametric space i.e. $d(x,y) \le max\{d(x,z), d(z,y)\}$ for all $z$

Edit2: As pointed out in comments this criteria makes a small nmber of algorithms (like nearest neighbour and furthest neighbour) admissable. It could still be important as this is the class of algorithm which is frequently used to find non convex clusters. However for me greater concern is that this criterion can be fulfilled only for ultrametric space and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ an ultrametric space can not have more than 3 points as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125520/largest-subset-of-mathbbr2-that-form-ultramtric-space).

Comment: I think only single-link clustering is "admissible". So that is a pretty useless definition, if all the interesting algorithms 'violate' this definition.

Comment: Above mentioned paper has evaluated each criteria for 5 algorithms. This criteria  makes single linkage (nearest neighbour) and farthest neighbour methods admissable while centroid clustering is not admissable. Other two methods are non hierarchical so not applicable. I agree that farthest neighbour isnt used much.

Comment: UPGMA and Ward are arguably very important.